# Как создать таймер в PHP, и по истечению его, бот сделает какое либо действие

Tags: php

Использую я библиотеку ReadBeanPHP для mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
// Создаем и запускаем таймер на 2 секунды
$w1 = new EvTimer(2, 0, function () {
    echo "2 секунды прошло\n";
});

// Создаем и запускаем таймер, который сработает через 2 секунды, после чего будет срабатывать
// раз в секунду, пока вы его вручную не остановите
$w2 = new EvTimer(2, 1, function ($w) {
    echo "вызывается раз в секунду, первое срабатывание через 2 секунды\n";
    echo "итерация = ", Ev::iteration(), PHP_EOL;

    // Останавливаем наблюдателя через 5 итераций
    Ev::iteration() == 5 and $w->stop();
    // Остановливаем наблюдателя, если следующий вызов приведет к десятой (или больше) итерации
    Ev::iteration() >= 10 and $w->stop();
});

// создаем остановленный таймер. Он будет неактивен, пока мы его не запустим
$w_stopped = EvTimer::createStopped(10, 5, function($w) {
    echo "Функция обратного вызова таймера, созданного остановленным\n";

    // Останавливаем наблюдателя через 2 итерации
    Ev::iteration() >= 2 and $w->stop();
});

// Запускаем событийный цикл, пока работает хотя бы один наблюдатель или пока не вызван Ev::stop()
Ev::run();

// Запускаем и смотрим, как он работает
$w_stopped->start();
echo "Запускаем одну итерацию\n";
Ev::run(Ev::RUN_ONCE);

echo "Перезапускаем второго наблюдателя и пытаемся отловить те же события, но не блокируем\n";
$w2->again();
Ev::run(Ev::RUN_NOWAIT);

$w = new EvTimer(10, 0, function() {});
echo "Запускаем блокирующий цикл\n";
Ev::run();
echo "END\n";
?>
```